# erro sintaxe MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou executando o seguinte script para criação de banco:

```
create database jogos;
use jogos;
create table jogo(
    codigojogo int auto_increment primary key,
    nomejogo varchar(40) not null
);

create table nivel(
    codigonivel int auto_increment primary key,
    dificuldade varchar(40) not null
);
create table jogonivel(
    codigon int,
    codigoj int,
    primary key(codigon, codigoj),
    constraint fk_codnivel foreign key (codigon) references nivel(codigonivel),
    constraint fk_codjogo foreign key (codigoj) references jogo(codigojogo),

);
insert into nivel (dificuldade) values ('facil');
insert into nivel (dificuldade) values ('medio');
insert into nivel (dificuldade) values ('dificil');
```

Quando executo, ele da erro na linha 8 perto do ')' porem não sei o que pode ser...
ja refiz a linha, troquei valores porem nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinha uma virgula sobrando no final da última linha do create da tabela jogonivel.

A sintaxe correta deve ser essa aqui abaixo:

```
create table jogonivel (
    codigon int,
    codigoj int,
    primary key(codigon, codigoj),
    constraint fk_codnivel foreign key (codigon) references nivel(codigonivel),
    constraint fk_codjogo foreign key (codigoj) references jogo(codigojogo)
);
```